# Typo3 link to single content element

Tags: hyperlink, content-management-system, typo3

My page tree looks like this:

```
Index:
  - List
  - SingleElement
  - Folder
```

"Folder" contains content elements that i would like to display in a form of a list on page "List". Each element of this list should link to (different) single content element. How can I create such links, and display single content element in page "SingleElement".

Answer (score 1):

2 different content elements are required to solve your questions.

**Menu of content elements**

To create a menu of content elements, go to your page *List* and add a content element "Special Menu" (inside the tab "Special elements"). As "Menu Type" please select `Section Index` and below select the page "List" in the "Selected Pages" field.

**Reference of a content element**

To reference a content element from one page at another page, use the content element "Insert record" which can be found in the tab "Special Element". At the field "Records" select the content elements you want to reuse.